# JDBC Update connection

Tags: java, jdbc, connection

First i perform a insert query for a user. Then i want to get the id of this user. It seems the connection to the DB is not up to date, because i get this SQLEception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set.
```

If i perform the SELECT statement on phpMyAdmin i get a result with the id.

**Connection**

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection
           ("jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":3306", user, password);
conn.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
```

**Methods**
add user method:

```
    public void addUser(String name, String vorname) {
        updateQuery("INSERT INTO Personen (pers_name, pers_vorname) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + vorname + "')");
}
```

this query dos work. I see the result in phpMyAdmin

get User id method:

```
    public ResultSet getUserId(String nachname, String vorname){
        String stringQuery = "SELECT pers_id FROM Personen WHERE pers_name = '" + nachname +"' AND pers_vorname = '" + vorname + "'";
        return query(stringQuery);
}
```

this method return empty result set

this is my `query` and `updateQuery` method:

```
    protected ResultSet query(String query) {
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        rs = null;
    }

    return rs;
}

protected void updateQuery(String query){
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Question**

is there a way to update the connection?

Comment: Please show us the code you're using for the query... we don't have enough information at the moment.

Comment: You are probably not comitting the transaction but without actual code it is difficult top tell. Have you looked at [Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)?

Comment: Please post your code..